# Writing program to help elementary students learn multiplication

Tags: java, methods, secure-random

> Write a program that will help an elementary school student learn multiplication. Use a SecureRandom object to produce two positive one-digit integers (you will need to look up how to do this). The program should then prompt the user with a question, such as
>
> How much is 6 times 7? The student then inputs the answer. Next, the program checks the student’s answer. If it’s correct, display the message "Very good!" and ask another multiplication question. If the answer is wrong, display the message "No. Please try again.>again." and let the student try the same question repeatedly until the student finally gets it right.
>
> A separate method should be used to generate each new question. This method should be called once when the application begins execution and each time the user answers the question correctly.

My question is do you have to make an if else statement == my public static mathQuestion and then have it output? I am lost on what to do after making the SecureRandom. I'm still new to Java.

I've tried doing an if-else statements after missing the question more than once but it has be done in a method.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.;

public class h_p1 {
    static SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
 public static int mathQuestion() {
    int n1 = rand.nextint(9) + 1;
    int n2 = rand.nextint(9) + 1;

    System.out.print("What is" + n1 + "x" + n2"?");
    return r1 * r2;
}


}

}
```

Comment: How many times a new multiplication question needs to be asked? If the count is fixed, use a `for` loop else a `do-while` loop. Inside the loop generate a new set of numbers and then use another `do-while` loop to check if the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Prompt for the answer
2. Check the answer by using an if statement.
3. If the answer is incorrect, prompt again.
4. If it correct, generate another question.

You will need to use loops in this situation.  It could take on 
different designs but you would need one for the reprompting and one for
the new question.

Imo, the best way to do the reprompting is to use a while statement with a settable boolean value.  If they get the answer correct, set the boolean to false
otherwise, keep prompting while true.  You could also use a for loop if you want to limit the number of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        generateRandomNumbers();

    }

    public static void generateRandomNumbers() {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        int n1 = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
        int n2 = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;

        generateQuestion(n1,n2);
    }

    public static void generateQuestion(int n1, int n2) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("What is " + n1 + " x " + n2+ " ?");

        int typedAnswer = sc.nextInt();

        if(typedAnswer == (n1*n2)) {
            System.out.println("Correct Answer");
            generateRandomNumbers();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            generateQuestion(n1,n2);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If the answer is correct it'll create new random numebrs and it'll create a new question. If the answer is wrong it needs to use the same random numbers. therefore, i passed it in parameters to generate the same question.

Comment: Do you always write such recursive codes? What is the space complexity of this code?

Comment: This the answer which came to my mind for this question. If you know any optimized code for this, add it as an answer. So i can learn it too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to this question that I could have thought for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        int numbOne = secureRandom.nextInt(9) + 1;
        int numbTwo = secureRandom.nextInt(9) + 1;
        int prod = numbOne * numbTwo;
        int response;
        do {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("What is the product of {0} and {1}", numbOne, numbTwo));
            response = scanner.nextInt();
            if (response != prod) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect answer! Try again");
            }
        } while (response != prod);
        System.out.println("Correct answer");
        System.out.println("Do you want to practice with another question (Y/N)?");
    } while (scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
}
```

It uses 2 `do-while` loops. The outer loop controls the number of times a question should be asked depending on user's choice and the inner loop checks the correctness of the answer given by the user.